# Tkinter...space invaders...shooting

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to implement the shooting mechanics. I need a continuous movement of the projectile but I cannot manage to code it. At this moment the program freezes when I press space. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

# creates window
window = Tk()
size = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.title("This is a window")
# set up geometry using string formatting operator %
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1000, 1000, 10, 10))
window.update()
# creates canvas
global canvas
canvas = Canvas(window, bg='green')

# pack is a layout manager
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.update()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 1000, 1000, 0, fill="orange", width=10, outline="white",         tag="border")

def shooting():
    c = canvas.coords("player")
    canvas.create_line(c[0],c[1] + 20,c[2],c[3],width=5,fill="yellow",tag="shot")

    while True:
        canvas.move("shot",0,20)
        canvas.update()

def on_key_press(event):
    global canvas
    c = canvas.coords("player")
    if event.keysym == 'Left' and c[0] > 0:
        canvas.move("player", -20,0)
        print(canvas.coords("player"))
    elif event.keysym == 'Right' and c[2] < 1000:
        canvas.move("player", 20, 0)
        print(canvas.coords("player"))
    elif event.keysym == 'space':
        shooting()


canvas.create_line(500, 950,500,1000, width=15, fill="red",tag="player")
canvas.bind_all('<Key>', on_key_press)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Program freeze because you have endless loop `while True` in `shooting()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tkinter you can't create endless loop `while True` or use `time.sleep()` because this way other functions in Tkinter can be executed by system.

You have to use

```
after(time_in_millisecond, function_name_without_()_and_arguments)
```

to call some function for example every 100ms.

You need somthing like this

```
def shooting():
    c = canvas.coords("player")
    canvas.create_line(c[0],c[1] + 20,c[2],c[3],width=5,fill="yellow",tag="shot")
    window.after(100, shooting_after)

def shooting_after():
    canvas.move("shot",0,20)
    canvas.update()
    window.after(100, shooting_after)
```

Now `space` doesn't freeze program but this simple example give you another problem:

When you press `space` you start new `"after loop"` so  when you press space 3 times you will have 3 `"after loops"`. You will need method to stop unused `"after loop"` :)